# Invertible function $f(x) = \frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{5x}{3} + 2 $

Tags: calculus, functions, inverse

How can I prove that $f(x) = \frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{5x}{3} + 2 $ is invertible.

First I choose variable $x$ for $y$ and tried to switch and simplified the function but I am  stuck. Need some help please.

Comment: It's not clear whether the $x^3$ and $x$ are in the numerator or denominator.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Nevertheless, by assuming the OP is smart, if he wanted to mean $(5/3)x$ he could have written $5x/3$, which is unambiguous.

Comment: i edited really sorry im new in latex

Comment: **sage >** solve(y==x^3/3+5*x/3+2,x): [x == -1/2*(3/2*y + 1/6*sqrt(81*y^2 - 324*y + 1472/3) - 3)^(1/3)*(I*sqrt(3) + 1) + 1/6*(-5*I*sqrt(3) + 5)/(3/2*y + 1/6*sqrt(81*y^2 - 324*y + 1472/3) - 3)^(1/3), x == -1/2*(3/2*y + 1/6*sqrt(81*y^2 - 324*y + 1472/3) - 3)^(1/3)*(-I*sqrt(3) + 1) + 1/6*(5*I*sqrt(3) + 5)/(3/2*y + 1/6*sqrt(81*y^2 - 324*y + 1472/3) - 3)^(1/3), x == (3/2*y + 1/6*sqrt(81*y^2 - 324*y + 1472/3) - 3)^(1/3) - 5/3/(3/2*y + 1/6*sqrt(81*y^2 - 324*y + 1472/3) - 3)^(1/3)]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$f'(x) = x^2+ 5/3 >0$$

So $f(x)$ is monotonically increasing and hence 1-1. Also the range is the reals so it is invertible.

Comment: but if i want to find the explicit inverse?

Comment: @Knight Then use Cardano's formulas (like the formulas for the quadratic equation but uglier). Google them.

Comment: okkk i wii do it thanks

Comment: I'll just mention that establishing monotonicity is important to the argument.  While a polynomial with even symmetry (only terms with even powers of $ \ x \ $ ) is not invertible, it is not sufficient for a polynomial to have odd symmetry in order for it to have an inverse:  to modify the problem here, $ \ \frac{1}{3}x^3 \ - \ \frac{5}{3}x \ $ is _not_ one-to-one.  (The "vertical shift" of 2 for the original function or this one does not affect the situation.)

Answer (score 4):

Both $g(x)=\frac{x^3}3$ and $h(x)=\frac{5x}3+2$ are [increasing functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increasing_function). (This should be clear if you know graphs of some basic functions.)

Sum of two (strictly) increasing functions is again an increasing function, therefore $f(x)=g(x)+h(x)$ is strictly increasing.

If a function is strictly increasing, then it is [injective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function).

Answer (score 0):

The function passes the horizontal line test, so it has an inverse function. The fact that the slope is always positive as the user44197 mentioned, implies that it passes the horizontal line test.